# loading huge database into memory visual c

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, heap-memory

We have a somewhat unusual c app in that it is a database of about 120 gigabytes, all of which is loaded into memory for maximum performance.  The machine it runs on has about a quarter terabyte of memory, so there is no issue with memory availability.  The database is read-only.

Currently we are doing all the memory allocation dynamically, which is quite slow, but it is only done once so it is not an issue in terms of time.

We were thinking about whether it would be faster, either in startup or in runtime performance, if we were to use global data structures instead of dynamic allocation.  But it appears that Visual Studio limits global data structures to a meager 4gb, even if you set the linker heap commit and reserve size much larger.

Anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: I would code such a beast on a Linux system, which can handle such loads (on 64 bits x86-64 = AMD64 systems). And filling 100 Gbytes take time. And it is not sure that a 120Gb database fills into 256GB RAM, because of overhead for every item.

Comment: I would love to move it to Linux, but that fight is over.  We have very fast solid state drive setup so that, once the memory is allocated, 120 Gbytes loads in less than 10 seconds.  And yes, 120 GB does fit; in fact, we have tried loading 2 copies (each 100GB) and there is no problem with memory available.

Comment: Just to make sure, it means you're running off a 2008 or 2003 Server R2, with a 64-bit process allright?

Comment: The platform is a quad E7 motherboard, 256GB memory, and several Revo SSDs.   I never have to turn the heat on in my office :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Startup performance**: If you're thinking of switching from dynamic to static global allocation, then I'd assume that you know how much you're allocating at compile time and there is a fixed number of allocations performed at runtime. I'd consider reducing the number of allocations performed, the actual call to new is the real bottleneck, not the actual allocation itself.

**Runtime performance**: No, it wouldn't improve runtime performance. Data structures of that size are going to end up on the heap, and subsequently in cache as they are read. To improve performance at runtime you should be aiming to improve locality of data so that data required subsequent to some you've just used, will end up on the same cache line, and paced in cache with the data you just used.

Both of these techniques I've used to great effect, efficiently ordering voxel data in 'batches', reducing the locality of data in a tree structure and reducing the number of calls to new, greatly increased the performance of a realtime renderer I worked on in a previous position. We're talking ~40GB voxel structures, possibly streaming of disk. Worked for us :).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to have your database as a [persistent memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) and then use the query part of your database to access that instead of dynamically allocated structures. It could be worth a try, I don't think performance would suffer that much (but of course will be slower).

Answer (score 1):

How many regions of memory are you allocating? **(1 x 120GB)** or **(120 Billion x 1 byte)** etc.

I believe the work done when dynamically allocating memory is proportional to the number of allocated regions rather than their size.

Depending on your data and usage (elaborate and we can be more specific), you can allocate a large block of heap memory (e.g. 120 GB) once then manage that yourself.

Comment: We are doing the memory management ourselves.  We are allocating 10 12 GB blocks, and then using pointers to split things up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you conducted an actual benchmark of your "in memory" solution versus having a well indexed read only table set on the solid state drives?   Depending upon the overall solution it's entirely possible that your extra effort yields only small improvements to the end user.   I happen to be aware of at least one solution approaching a half a petabyte of storage where the access pattern is completely random with an end user response time of less than 10 seconds with all data on disk.

Comment: Yes, many benchmarks, and the difference of having the stuff in memory is huge.  Random access speed is not the issue.  You could have 1000's of petabytes accessible in a fraction of a second with a well-constructed index, with or without storing it on ssd's.  The issue here is the need to crunch through gigabytes of data as quickly as possible.